# Maximum eigenvalue of product of two matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Let $A$ and $B$ be two Hermitian matrices. I wanted to know if there is any relation between the maximum eigenvalue of $AB$ and that of $A$ and $B$. Is the following relation true?
$\lambda_{\text{max}}\left(AB\right)\le \lambda_{\text{max}}\left(A\right)\lambda_{\text{max}}\left(B\right)$

If it is true, then is this relation valid when $A$ and $B$ are real.

Comment: Does $\lambda_{\text{max}}$ denote the largest eigenvalue by magnitude?

Comment: Yes. It is the maximum eigenvalue of the matrix

Comment: What I was asking is if a matrix has eigenvalues $2$ and $-4$, what is $\lambda_{\max}$? $2$ or $4$?

Comment: Ohh. It is the maximum eigenvalue, including sign. So, $\lambda_{\text{max}} = 2$ for the example you gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are $\color{blue}{\rm HPD}$, then
$$
\begin{split}
\color{red}{\lambda_{\max}(AB)}
&=
\lambda_{\max}(B^{1/2}AB^{1/2})
\\&=
\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{x^*B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}x}{x^*x}
\\&=
\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{x^*Ax}{x^*B^{-1}x}
\\&=
\max_{x\neq 0}\left(\frac{x^*Ax}{x^*x}\right)\left(\frac{x^*x}{x^*B^{-1}x}\right)
\\&\color{red}{\leq}
\max_{x\neq 0}\left(\frac{x^*Ax}{x^*x}\right)\max_{y\neq 0}\left(\frac{y^*y}{y^*B^{-1}y}\right)
\\&=
\max_{x\neq 0}\left(\frac{x^*Ax}{x^*x}\right)\max_{y\neq 0}\left(\frac{y^*By}{y^*y}\right)
\\&=
\color{red}{\lambda_{\max}(A)\lambda_{\max}(B)}.
\end{split}
$$
Otherwise, as already indicated, the inequality does not need to be true if $A$ or $B$ is indefinite. By the continuity argument, it can also be extended for the case when $A$ and $B$ are only semi-definite.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=B=\operatorname{diag}(-2,1)$, then $AB = \operatorname{diag}(4,1)$, but
$\lambda_\max (AB) = 4$, $\lambda_\max (A) = \lambda_\max (B)= 1$.

If the matrices are positive semi-definite, then $\|A\|=\lambda_\max(A)$ (since
$A$ is unitarily diagonalisable) and the
spectral norm is submultiplicatve, hence the result holds.

Comment: What if $A,B$ are positive definite?

Comment: Isn't $\lambda_{\text{max}}$ of a matrix the spectral norm of the matrix. If it is, then it should satisfy the norm inequality.

Comment: @user146290: The maximum modulus eigenvalue is the spectral norm, but here there is no modulus here, nor positive definiteness.